# Split column and take the last object of the resulting list in R

Tags: r

I have a column of strings. The strings contain data points separated by commas. I need to split each string in the column by the comma and then take the very last object in the resulting list.

```
col1
"1, 2, 3"
"2, 5, 7, 9, 11"
"1, 4, 6, 8"
```

The result I need is:

```
result
"3"
"11"
"8"
```

I can figure out how to do this with only one row, but I need to do it with the entire column. I figure I need to use sapply, but I can't figure out how it works with the tail function...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
> sapply(strsplit(col1, ", ", fixed=TRUE), tail, 1)
[1] "3"  "11" "8"
```

If your column is not already a character vector, wrap `col1` with `as.character`.

Comment: Easier than placing the list col1col1 somewhere that read.tab≤read.table can get at it, then taking the last element of each row.  But, if the OP started out with this text in a file, I'd recommend reading it in properly :-)

Comment: Sorry -- I tried to edit, but something in my browser setup is duplicating crap.  Should just be  "... the list `col1` ... `read.table` can get at..."